# Net::Telnet, trying to read a output

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read this output from my equipment, how i have to use print and waitfor, i'm not being sucessful.

This is the output....

```
zSH> get v52-interface-group 1
v52-interface-group  1
name-id: --------------------->  {CTAA-024}
local-interface-id: ---------->  {1024}
local-prov-variant: ---------->  {2}
prov-variant-request: -------->  {norequest}
admin-status: ---------------->  {inservice}
pstn-layer-3-start-address: -->  {1}
isdn-env-func-start-address: ->  {1}
port-alignment-request: ------>  {norequest}
national-pstn-region: -------->  {brazil}
switch-vendor: --------------->  {nortel}
protocol-spec: --------------->  {edition2}
startup-check-link-id: ------->  {false}
startup-unblock-user-ports: -->  {false}
link-oos-timer: -------------->  {2500}
link-is-timer: --------------->  {200}

v52-link has 16 elements. Display [a]ll, [n]one, a [s]ubset, or [q]uit? q
```

This is the part of my code where i'm trying to read....

```
$string = "Display [a]ll, [n]one, a [s]ubset, or [q]uit?";
$tel->print("get v52-interface-group 1");
$tel->waitfor(String => $string);
@out = $tel->cmd('q');
print @out;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to protect the square brackets in `waitfor()` using a **regex**.

```
$string = "/Display\s+\[a\]ll,\s+\[n\]one,\s+a\s+\[s\]ubset,\s+or\s+\[q\]uit\?/";
$tel->waitfor($string);
```

Comment: This way i have this problem 
pattern match timed-out at v52.pl line 49 
and i'm sending the cmd, the problem is i cant read that output tha i need

Comment: If it solved for you, thanks to show how with your code to add it as your own new response here. Like this, people that will have the same problems will find this in our searches. This is how SO websites works, thanks.